# Update property asynchronously c# MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, mvvm

The XAML is bind to a ViewModel `MainVM` that loads 2 other sub-ViewModels `SubVM1` and `SubVM2`. I'm using the [asynchronous command presented by John Thiriet](https://johnthiriet.com/mvvm-going-async-with-async-command/). My intend : use a command defined in the MainVM, using an asynchronous function from SubVM1 to update a property from SubVM2.
(XAML)

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MainVM x:Key="main"/>
    <local:SubVM2 x:Key="subvm2"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding MyValue}" DataContext="{StaticResource subvm2}" FontSize="40"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}" DataContext="{StaticResource main}" Width="100" Height="100" Content="GO"/>
</Grid>
```

MainVM

```
class MainVM : VMBase
{
    private SubVM1 _subvm1;
    private SubVM2 _subvm2;
    private bool _isBusy;

    public SubVM1 Subvm1
    {
        get => _subvm1;
        set
        { _subvm1 = value; OnPropertyChanged("Subvm1"); }
    }
    public SubVM2 Subvm2
    {
        get => _subvm2;
        set
        { _subvm2 = value; OnPropertyChanged("Subvm2"); }
    }
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get => _isBusy;
        set
        { _isBusy = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsBusy"); }
    }

    public IAsyncCommand MyCommand { get; set; }

    public MainVM()
    {
        Subvm1 = new SubVM1();
        Subvm2 = new SubVM2();
        MyCommand = new AsyncCommand(Increment, MuchBusiness);
    }

    private async Task Increment()
    {
        try
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            await Subvm1.MyAsyncFunc(Subvm2.MyValue);
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }

    private bool MuchBusiness()
    {
        return !IsBusy;
    }

}
```

SubVM1

```
class SubVM1 : VMBase
{
    public async Task MyAsyncFunc(double MyValue)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < 20)
            {
                MyValue = i;
                i++;
                Console.WriteLine(MyValue);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

SubVM2

```
class SubVM2 : VMBase
{
    private double _myValue;
    public double MyValue
    {
        get => _myValue;
        set
        { _myValue = value; OnPropertyChanged("MyValue"); }
    }

    public SubVM2() { }
}
```

I tried using [this article from Stephen Cleary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/march/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-data-binding). This was really instructive, but I only understood I was doing it wrong. I don't seem to be able to figure out how to use the code he provided. Plus I could not find the source code which usually really helps me understanding.
I have also read about [dispatchers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/april/mvvm-multithreading-and-dispatching-in-mvvm-applications), but same, no source code
There was [this solution](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/441752/Async-MVVM-Modern-UI) that aimed at modifying `OnPropertyChanged`, however that was from a win8 app, and I could not extrapolate from there.

Comment: As a note, a `public async Task` method that does nothing but calling `await Task.Run()` should not be async: `public Task MyAsyncFunc(double MyValue) { return Task.Run(() => { ... }); }`

Comment: @Clemens Even if I don't want to return anything ? In the "real" code, this Async function operates a load bench, and I want that operation to be treated on a separte thread.

Comment: `await MyAsyncFunc()` would already await the Task.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, was tired when reading this yesterday. There are indeed a bunch of UI related updated before and after the await Task.Run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Detailed solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/april/mvvm-multithreading-and-dispatching-in-mvvm-applications), and the [link to get the file related to the article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/april/april-2014-code-downloads)

I ended up using MVVMLight. All function from this library are preceded with `GS`

**XAML**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" >
    <Label Content="{Binding SubVM2.MyValue}" FontSize="40"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding SubVM1.OkCommand}" Width="100" Height="100" Content="GO"/>
</Grid>
```

**MainVM**

```
public class MainVM : VMBase
{
    public SubVM1 SubVM1 { get; }
    public SubVM2 SubVM2 { get; } = new SubVM2();

    public MainVM()
    {
        SubVM1 = new SubVM1(SubVM2);

        //Subvm2 = new SubVM2();
    }
}
```

**SubVM1** (usage of IsBusy as a canexecute parameter)

```
using GS = GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
[...]
public class SubVM1 : VMBase
{
    private SubVM2 _subVM2 { get; set; }
    private bool _isBusy;
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get => _isBusy;
        set
        { _isBusy = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsBusy"); }
    }

    public SubVM1() { }

    public SubVM1(SubVM2 SubVM2)
    {
        _subVM2 = SubVM2; ;
    }


    private GS.RelayCommand _okCommand;
    public GS.RelayCommand OkCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _okCommand
                    ?? (_okCommand = new GS.RelayCommand(
                        async () =>
                        {
                            IsBusy = true;
                            Console.WriteLine(IsBusy);
                            await Task.Run(
                                () =>
                                {
                                    // This is a background operation!
                                    IsBusy = true;
                                    _subVM2.MyValue = 0;
                                    while (_subVM2.MyValue < 30)
                                    {
                                        _subVM2.MyValue++;
                                        // Sleep for a while
                                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                                    }
                                });
                            IsBusy = false;
                            Console.WriteLine(IsBusy);
                        },()=> { return !IsBusy; },false));
        }
    }
}
```

**SubVM2**

```
public class SubVM2 : VMBase {
    private double _myValue;
    public double MyValue
    {
        get => _myValue;
        set
        { _myValue = value; OnPropertyChanged("MyValue"); }
    }

    public SubVM2() { } }
```

**ViewModelLocator**

```
public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the ViewModelLocator class.
        /// </summary>
        public ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

            ////if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
            ////{
            ////    // Create design time view services and models
            ////    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DesignDataService>();
            ////}
            ////else
            ////{
            ////    // Create run time view services and models
            ////    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
            ////}

            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainVM>();
        }

        public MainVM Main
        {
            get
            {
                return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainVM>();
            }
        }

        public static void Cleanup()
        {
            // TODO Clear the ViewModels
        }
    }
```

I don't know how pretty this solution is, so I'll wait a little bit before marking it as the answer. It does the job for me though ! :)

Comment: Don't ever use `Thread.Sleep()` inside an async method - use `await Task.Delay()` instead

Comment: @Peregrine Why is that ?

Comment: The whole point of async is to avoid blocking threads.